# Getting back a uniqueidentifier from an inserted record

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I develop a C# app that can switch between 2 databases - SQL-Server and a local SQL-Compact DB.

When inserting something I want to get back the inserted ID which is a `uniqueidentifier`.

`ExecuteScalar()` does not work for `uniqueidentifier`. Only when using `output inserted.id`.

But `output inserted.id` is not supported by SQL-Compact.

Is there a way to get back a `uniqueidentifier` in both databases?

Comment: You could declare a uniqueidentifier in your code as a variable, insert it and then cast it to a varchar in your select so you can use ExecuteScalar.

Comment: Or you can always generate a new guid in C# as that is one benefit of using guids - they can be created in the DB or the App since they are globally unique.

Comment: One of the core features of the `GUID` is that you can generate it from anywhere you want. That's contrary to the auto-increment identifiers which can only be generated by the database. So I suggest that you make use of that feature and generate your `GUID`s in your C# code, then no need to bother with returning generated IDs from the database. Honestly, when I see code that generate the `GUID` at the database, I always wonder why `GUID` was used in the first place because auto-increment integers would perform better in that case. But there are rare exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that with SQL Server Compact.

If you must use GUIDs, the only way is to create the GUID on the client, not ask the database engine for the generated value.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you could do it using a variable.

```
declare @GUID uniqueidentifier = newid()

insert (YourColumns)
values(@GUID)

select convert(varchar(36), @GUID) as MyKey
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work in SQL-Compact. But I keep trying

Comment: @juergend - see the comments under your question about generating the guid in code.

Comment: Only if there is no other way. I would have to refactor 10k code lines.

Answer (score 0):

Just realised that this is a duplicate of the answer of @Sean Langem I am leaving it up because it does add more detail which may be useful to the OP.

---

This is perhaps not the most elegant solution (that being to generate the GUID in the application), however I believe that it should resolve your issue.  Please note that I have only tested this against SQL Server, not SQL Compact.

Use ExecuteScalar() to return your ID, however convert it to a string (varchar) in the stored procedure, then back to a GUID in your application.

The below example is a very simple one for demonstration purposes, and the code is in VB.Net and does not ensure the connection is closed, handle exceptions, etc.

Sample Stored procedure returning a UNIQUEIDENTIFER Value as VARCHAR:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
AS 

    DECLARE @id uniqueidentifier
    SET @id = NEWID()

    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(38), @id)
GO
```

Sample .Net code to call the database and retrieve the String, then convert to guid.

```
Sub main()

    Dim id As Guid
    Dim stringId As String

    Using con As New SqlConnection("Server=<server>;Database=<DB>;Trusted_Connection=True;")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("test", con)
            cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

            con.Open()
            stringId = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        End Using
    End Using

    id = New Guid(stringId)

End Sub
```

Comment: `declare` is not supported in SQL-Compact